# Displaying node forms in panels

Tags: nodes, panels, views, entities

In a multi user environment, how do I get a panel to display the node content form (to enter text) of a user knowing that each user has such a (separate) node. In other words, a visitor on Jack's panel page would be presented with Jack's form and be able to write something there, but if visiting John, he would be presented with John's form.

I tried the Form Block module but it shows the node of the viewing user, not the user being viewed, on all users' panel pages.  Is there a way for this to add an argument or contextual filter in panels so that each user's form displays appropriately?

I should add that the nodes are back linked (Entity Reference) to their users.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you.
:)

Comment: What is the connection between the user and the node page? This is definitely doable, but I need to understand how you've fitted the two entities together. :)

Comment: I edited the question before seeing your response. The node is created when the user registers and is back linked to him/her at that time (Rules.) The Entity Reference field is on the user entity.  Thanks. :)

Comment: I wanted to re-phrase the question to be more generic. I posted this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/80242/how-do-i-include-linked-data-to-a-page-in-page-manager Let me know if that's helpful for you. :)

Comment: Is it helpful? An understatement...  It's just great, you did it...!  :)   

When I post a comment it goes directly to the user whose page I am visiting and not mine or anyone else's. Now, I have to work on my views for the proper display. Originally, I was hoping to be able to substitute the comment form for the node form. The reason being that Drupal does not allow users to delete comments. I figured it would be possible if nodes masqueraded as comments. But a node, once published is published and you can't attach other nodes to it like a chain (at least, I don't think so.)

Comment: (Continued...) Only a great mind can come up with a simple solution to a complex problem! :) Thank you very much for your very valuable input. I am sure other members of the community will appreciate it too! :)

Comment: Haven't used comments much, but surely there is a way to delete them? Sounds like another question ;) So if the other question helped, I'll recommend this one be closed as a duplicate of the one I posted, as it's more generic and hopefully can help others with similar issues. :)

Comment: yes, you can delete them by hovering around the tail end of the "XX hours ago." A little X will show up. :)