# How do I include linked data to a Page in Page manager?

Tags: panels, chaos-tool-suite

Given two pieces of data, for example two entities, two nodes; when viewing one of them, how do I pull in data for the other one into Page manager/Panels?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the image below, one can see the `Context` settings for a particular `Page variant`. Under `Contexts`, one can also see `Relationships`.

`Relationships` are what one uses to tell Page manager to pull in more, related, data, based on the `arguments` that the `page` is built around.

With two nodes related to each other with a reference field, and the base node being supplied through the URI on `node/%nid`, we can add `Node from reference` as seen in the screenshot below.

Further content types (and other options) will now be available in Panels for display.

[image: How to add relationships]